# What is the difference between background:url(../images/nameofimage.jpg); and background:url(images/nameofimage.jpg);?

Tags: css

Nine times out of ten I'll write:

```
background:url(../images/nameofimage.jpg);
```

However, I've just run into an issue where my CSS is only working when the syntax is:

```
background:url(images/nameofimage.jpg);
```

I'm almost positive I've run into this before where I suddenly needed to add the periods and slashes in CSS.

Comment: `../` points to the parent directory. Here's a document explaining the difference: http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm

Comment: And for a full overview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)

Comment: It all depends on how you layout your files and folders @Pekka gives a  good example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let say you have a directory structure like this:

```
~ Root
 - Styles
  * site.css
 - Images
  * nameofimage.jpg
```

Then its not posible to write in your style.css 
`background:url(images/nameofimage.jpg);` because you search for `~/styles/images/nameofimage.jpg` and this file does not exits.

When you write `background:url(../images/nameofimage.jpg);` you go back one folder and then search for `images/nameofimage.jpg` so it goes to the file `~images/nameofimage.jpg`.

With `../` you can browse back in folders.

Answer (score 1):

`'../'` means you go up a directory

Answer (score 1):

When you say `background:url(../images/nameofimage.jpg);` it means you are pointing to the parent directory images directory.

When you say `background:url(images/nameofimage.jpg);` it means you are pointing to the images directory in the same folder (the folder in which your css has).